# Do closed hypersurfaces separate the euclidean space?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homology

The following extension of the Jordan Curve Theorem is well known: every closed connected hypersurface of the sphere $\mathbb S^N$ separates $S^N$ into exactly two connected components. As a consequence, every compact connected hypersurface of the euclidean space $\mathbb R^N$ separates $\mathbb R^N$ into exactly two connected components.

Does this result keep its validity if the word `compact' is replaced by *closed*? With other words, is it true that every closed connected hypersurface of the euclidean space $\mathbb R^N$ separates $\mathbb R^N$ into exactly two connected components?

Comment: You have to define more precisely that is a "closed connected hypersurface" to make this meaningful.

Comment: Usually "closed" in this context means compact and without boundary.  Your question appears to be about the case where you drop compactness, i.e. your manifold simply has no boundary, like $\mathbb R^{N-1}$.  In that case the answer is no, as Euclidean spaces are diffeomorphic to open balls.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko It's possible that the that this is asking for the hypersurface to be proper (i.e. so it is closed as a subset).

Comment: In the case of the point-set topology "closed" then the answer is yes, those do separate.   The proof is basically the same as when dealing with compact manifolds.